# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined django graphos

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
  $.plot(
    $("#line_chart"), 
    [{"data": [[2005, 205], [2015, 210], [2015, 12], [2014, 122], [2015, 12], [2015, 2]], "label": "PlacedStudent"}], 
    {"series": {"lines": {"show": "true"}}, "legend": {"position": "ne"}, "xaxis": {"mode": "categories"}, "title": "PlaceMentReport"}
  );
 });
</script>
```

What is the wrong here , I am getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Your jquery file is missing .

Comment: Add jQuery before you use $, https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Include jquery library.

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: can be caused by numerous issues, google the error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29729383/2025923 might help you